# Info.plist how to merge Google with Facebook Configuration

Tags: ios, info.plist

i've configured this Info.plist for google and then facebook for signing in with social.
The problem when added facebook it works but google sign in not working. The console debugger it 'Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes: com.googleusercontent.apps.************************'

Here is my configuration Info.plist file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.**********************</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <!-- facebook -->
    
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>fb*************</string>
      </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>***************</string>
    <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
    <string>****************</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>Nome app</string>
    <!--Per usare una delle finestre di dialogo di Facebook (ad es. Accedi, Condividi, inviti a installare l'app ecc.) che consentono di eseguire il passaggio di un'app alle app Facebook-->
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fbapi</string>
      <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thanks for any appreciated help. I need for this morning please.

Comment: Just a guess but now you have 2 CFBundleURLTypes arrays in your info.plist. So only one is taken into account. Merge both .

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue but instead of google I had vk.
Still the solution is the same.

1. Initial code

```
<!-- VK Configuration -->
   <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
   <array>
   <dict>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
       <string>vk12345</string>
   </array>
   </dict>
   </array>

   <!--  -->
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key> 
   <array> 
       <string>vk</string> 
       <string>vk-share</string> 
       <string>vkauthorize</string> 
   </array>
   <!--  -->
   <key>VKAppId</key>
   <string>{YOUR_VK_ID}</string>
   <!-- Facebook Config -->
   <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
   <array>
   <dict>
       <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
       <array>
       <string>fb{YOUR_FB_ID}</string>
       </array>
   </dict>
   </array>


   <key>FacebookAppID</key>
   <string>{YOUR_FB_ID}</string>
   <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
   <string>{YOUR_FB_TOKEN}</string>
   <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
   <string>{YOUR_FB_NAME}</string>
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
   <string>fbapi</string>
   <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
   </array>
   <!--  -->
```

2. Merged code

```
    <!-- MERGED -->
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>vk{YOUR_VK_ID}</string>
        <string>fb{YOUR_FB_ID}</string>
    </array>
    </dict>
    </array>

    <!-- MERGED -->
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key> 
    <array> 
        <string>vk</string> 
        <string>vk-share</string> 
        <string>vkauthorize</string> 
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    </array>
    <key>VKAppId</key>
    <string>{YOUR_VK_ID}</string>

    <!-- Facebook Config -->

    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>{YOUR_FB_ID}</string>
    <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
    <string>{YOUR_FB_TOKEN}</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>Katharsis</string>

    <!--  -->
```

Comment: Persons reading this post in the future may consider your answer more helpful if it includes a brief description of why your solution works.